# Process function for Join (with side input) on Apache beam ( Cloud DataFlow ) not appending new recording in else part

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying **join** on Beam with side input.

The join works ( with side input ) and updates the base employee details for common key.
In my custom requirement, I also want to append the new employee id to the existing (updated data set ) post the join.

Both the PCollections has same layout, emp_id is the common key.
My job is running on Cloud Data Flow.

Apache Beam process function ***Else*** not working as expected, where I am trying to append the new empid , part of the new input. Here keys are different in this input Pcollection.

**Process function :**

```
def process_history_details(self, row, new_emp_details):
    import traceback
    result = row.copy()
    try:
        result.update(new_emp_details[row['emp_id']])
    except KeyError as err:
        pass
    else:
        result.update(new_emp_details[row['emp_id']]) 
        for k in new_emp_details[k['emp_id']]:
            if k not in result['emp_id']:
               result.update(new_emp_details)
    return result
```

**Call to this function :**

```
history_data = (
        p
        | 'Read historical data from BigQuery ' >> beam.io.Read(
    beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=emp_hist_data, use_standard_sql=True))
        |'Join Data with sideInput' >> beam.Map(datalakecomparison.process_history_details, AsDict(*new_emp_data*))
```

The *new_emp_data* dictionary is generated as mentioned below :

```
new_emp_data = (
            p
            | 'Read base from BigQuery ' >> beam.io.Read(
            beam.io.BigQuerySource(query= new_emp_query, use_standard_sql=True))
            |
            'New Employee details' >> beam.Map(
        lambda x:(
            x['emp_id'], x))
            )
```

Using the belwo  query to pull the data, then the data is passed ( as mentioned above) using the lambda function.

```
def new_emp_query(self):
    new_emp_query = """
    SELECT 
    emp_id, 
    emp_name,
    emp_code,
    emp_unit,
    emp_sal 
    FROM snow.new_emp_data 
    """
    return new_emp_query
```

Current Input :

**Historical data**

emp_id,emp_name,emp_code,emp_unit,emp_sal

1,A,34,45,70000

2,B,35,45,80000

3,C,34,45,90000

**new employee data**

emp_id,emp_name,emp_code,emp_unit,emp_sal

1,A,34,45,1000000

6,F,36,47,90000

**Current Output:**

emp_id,emp_name,emp_code,emp_unit,emp_sal

1,A,34,45,1000000

2,B,35,45,80000

3,C,34,45,90000

**Expected Output :**

emp_id,emp_name,emp_code,emp_unit,emp_sal

1,A,34,45,1000000

2,B,35,45,80000

3,C,34,45,90000

**6,F,36,47,90000**

*Emp_id 6 is what I wish to append to the result*

Comment: Your 2 datasources are in BigQuery? What is the sink? BigQuery? a file?

Comment: yes they are coming from big query.

Comment: So, why you don't simply use a SQL query for merging/transforming the values?

Comment: yes, that will be my last resort, was checking if I can do it this way. I even tried result.update(new_emp_details), as shown in the sample code,  before the return but that operation failed whereas dictionaries allow update

Comment: BigQuery query is my first recommendation: quicker, cheaper, powerful, codeless (only sql query). If you can do with BigQuery, it's perfect! If you are in a dead end, don't hesitate to ask for help here!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your `process_history_details` function.

 When you try to append `6,F,36,47,90000`, you get a **KeyError**, the **except** clause passes and your **else** statement is not triggered.

You can check that behaviour with a simple test function like below:

```py
def lookup(x):
    a = {'Rick':1}
    try:
        print(a[x])
    except KeyError as err:
        print('pass')
        pass
    else:
        print(a[x])

lookup('Morty')
```

Output:

> pass

---

### You could either:

- Get rid of the **else** statement:

```py
def process_history_details(self, row, new_emp_details):
    import traceback
    result = row.copy()
    try:
        result.update(new_emp_details[row['emp_id']])
    except KeyError as err:
        result.update(new_emp_details[row['emp_id']]) 
        for k in new_emp_details[k['emp_id']]:
            if k not in result['emp_id']:
               result.update(new_emp_details)
    return result
```

- Or use an **if** statement:

```py
def process_history_details(self, row, new_emp_details):
    import traceback
    result = row.copy()
    if row['emp_id'] in new_emp_details.keys():
        result.update(new_emp_details[row['emp_id']])
    else:
        result.update(new_emp_details[row['emp_id']]) 
        for k in new_emp_details[k['emp_id']]:
            if k not in result['emp_id']:
               result.update(new_emp_details)
    return result
```